# Save user logined user token Larave + Vue

Tags: typescript, authentication, vuejs3, laravel-9

I have created simple Laravel9 + Vue3 TypeScript project for login and registration.
Login and registration both working nice.
Here is my login controller.

```
 public function login(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'errors' => $validator->errors()
        ]);
    }

    if(Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $token = $user->createToken('api_token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'success' => 'Login successful',
            'user' => $user,
            'access_token' => $token
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'error' => 'invalid creadentials'
    ]);
}
```

When everything is validated I am sending response with user information and token,
and I am saving this information in vuex store like this:

```
    store.commit("setUser", {
      fullname: res.data.user.full_name,
      email: res.data.user.email,
      token: res.data.access_token,
    });
    router.push({name: "Home"});
```

Also this working fine and saving all necessary information in the vuex store,
but when restarting page all information that I saved in the vuex store is lost.
So please give me any advice what can I do to not lose data and token when restarting page. I don't want to save it in localstorage because its not safe to save token in localstorage.

Comment: it must be saved locally somehow.  localStorage or cookies.  try [vuex-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist).  there are many other things you can do to increase safety.  short-lived tokens, validation on load, checking for and fixing any code vulnerable to XSS attacks, etc.  localStorage doesn't have to be automatically considered unsafe.